# How to add an onClick event to a variable outside my class extends?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

So I'm using React/Redux here. Outside of my class extends I have

```
const Question10 = () => (<div>
                  <p>Question goes here</p>
                  <input placeholder="type in your answer" type="text"></input>
                  <button>Submit Answer</button>
                  <Link to="/question/9">Previous Question</Link>
                  </div>)
```

and right below that I start my class extends

```
class Questions extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.buttonClick = this.buttonClick.bind(this)
  }

  buttonClick(){
    console.log('button clicked');
  }

  render(){
    return (
          <Router>
            <div className="questions">
              <Route path ="/question/10" component={Question10}  />
            </div>
          </Router>

    )
  }
}
```

In the `const Question10` I tried `<button onClick={this.buttonClick}></button>` and in the Route component, I tried the same thing. How do I make an onClick event happen in this circumstance? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)

```
this.buttonClick = this.buttonClick.bind(this)
```

in constructor is unnecessary

2) Pass the function to `onClick` property

a) First, make `Question10` accepts the parameter and pass to button

```
const Question10 = (clickHandler) => (<div>
              <p>Question goes here</p>
              <input placeholder="type in your answer" type="text"></input>
              <button onCLick={clickHandler}>Submit Answer</button>
              <Link to="/question/9">Previous Question</Link>
              </div>)
```

b) Pass the handler to `Question10`

```
<Route path ="/question/10" component={Question10(this.buttonClick.bind(this))}  />
```